# How does this matrix act on a tree?

Tags: representation-theory, trees, p-adic-number-theory

I understand that $SL(2,\Bbb{Q}_p)$ acts on an infinite (p+1)-regular tree, and that the subgroup  $SL(2,\Bbb{Z}_p)$ acts by fixing a vertex, rotating the (p+1) neighbors by the $SL(2,\Bbb{Z}/p)$-action, the neighbors of those neighbors by the $SL(2,\Bbb{Z}/p^2)$-action, etc.

How does the matrix 
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
1  & 1/p \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
act on the tree?  I keep getting confused.

Comment: Are we talking about the Bruhat-Tits tree? Would the group acting on it not be $PGL_2(\Bbb{Q}_p)$ rather than $SL_2(\Bbb{Q}_p)$? And the action of that matrix the same as that of $\begin{pmatrix}
p & 1\\
0 & p
\end{pmatrix}$?